# Jobs "Not Found" but being advertised to me regardless

Tags: discussion, support

Basically I've got jobs being advertised to me as per usual, but this is the second one that doesn't seem to link anywhere:

[image: not found - job]

The above job has the following link:

- [Job Link](http://clc.stackoverflow.com/ct?an=Y2NiUFRZtdy28rIHw007XQZWRoaNH5lYWRgYGdgZgIDlgjMzQ4c6c6tLyWN7VrA4IxeQYGEGSTICCX4WIBFhzMxgGJjhtd_ulT0LRBUDiqrtrswMMmEvNnzjPAdTADYGbAJI1bIvTAwv7vMf2KV4GlMBE5DQkge7hYnFxjGUFWSfAEMAkAUymIFZBMgCmcDABGLde2z3Yerk38pO9wA&at=0&tz=3&ti=209752&tr=large-sidebar-orange-looking)
- [Actual Link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/16863/ruby-on-rails-developer-9mmedia)

Here's another one:

[image: job not found 2]

- [Job Link](http://clc.stackoverflow.com/ct?an=Y2NiODt7n5xd5WUPhpt2ugysjAwOlkysAgxMDOzcDAwMTBecmRlWO6wWnFj82J4VLM7IxcDIwMIMlGRhBBL8LEDivxUzQ6BTQn2X5Wt7ZogqBpgqMXmwIUwsNo6hrCCFAgwBQBZHRtyp4oDdPKprAQ&at=0&tz=3&ti=211711&tr=small-sidebar-tag-themed-php)
- [Actual Link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/17333/systems-engineer-mongodb-10gen-mongodb)

This is the third link that I've clicked to check out that redirects me to a "Job Not Found" page.

It's obviously not a **major** issue or flaw or anything like that, but it does leave a level of dissatisfaction when wanting to view these posts having false hope raised.